Solving for $m, n \in \mathbb N$ in the Diophantine equation: $n^2 = 2^m - 7$.
Question:
Find all $m, n \in \mathbb N$ which satisfy:
$$n^2 = 2^m - 7$$
So far:
Running Python trial-and-error for $m < 50$ outputs the solutions:
$$(m, n) = (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 5), (7, 11), (15, 181)$$
Obviously, the parity of $n$ is odd. Apart from that, here's my attempt on reducing the equation modulo $9$...
We see that $\mathcal O_9(2) = 6$ as shown below:
$$2 \equiv 2\pmod 9$$
$$2^2 \equiv 4\pmod 9$$
$$2^3 \equiv -1\pmod 9$$
$$2^4 \equiv -2\pmod 9$$
$$2^5 \equiv -4\pmod 9$$
$$2^6 \equiv 1\pmod 9$$
As for $n$:
$$n \equiv 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -4, -3, -2, -1\pmod 9 \Longrightarrow n^2 \equiv 0, 1, 4, 0, -2, -2, 0, 4, 1\pmod 9$$
$$n^2 + 7 \equiv -2, -1, 2, -2, -4, -4, -2, 2, -1\pmod 9$$
I don't see a way forward with this though...
Any help would be really appreciated.

See here, for $n^2=2^m+17$. This is very similar. Actually, this duplicate solves it, $n^2=2^m+D$ for $D=-7$. The solutions of $2^n-7=m^2$ are indeed exactly $(m, n) = (1, 3), (3, 4), (5, 5), (11, 7), (181, 15)$

To avoid duplicate questions :
https://approach0.xyz/search/

@Guruprasad approach0 wasn't working the last  2 or 3 days.

@Zwim it is working. Now I tried
